# Android Studio SDK manager doesn't show the candidate packages(How to install CMake)

Tags: android-studio, cmake, android-sdk-manager

From the post "[Add C and C++ Code to Your Project](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html)",

> You can install these components using the SDK Manager:
>
> From an open project, select Tools > Android > SDK Manager 
>   from the menu bar. Click the SDK Tools tab. Check the boxes next to LLDB,
>   CMake, and NDK, as shown in figure 1.

there is a image shows
 [image: Installing LLDB, CMake, and the NDK from the SDK Manager.]
But my Android Studio is not like that.
I upload a image to show my Android Studio sdk manager settings:
[image]

I googled for a while, but I didn't find anything useful. My PC is win10 64bit, I run Android Stdio 64bit, version is 2.2, I use the Android Studio bunndle version(I assume the AS and the sdk are one thing).
I also run Android Studio 2.3 on another PC, I check the sdk manager on version 2.3, it looks like behaving the same. I also try to run AS in the administrator role. it looks like behaving the same too.

The different on the AS2.2 and AS2.3 is that I can run the sdkmanager command in a win shell to install the CMake/LLDB on the PC that has AS 2.3, but I can't find the sdkmanager command in the SDK folder which is associated with the AS 2.2, so I go to download a standlone command line tools from the developer.android.com, I unzip the downloaded file and get a fold named "tool", what should I do? shold I merge the downloaded tool folder into the android_sdk/tools?

The below image is the sdk settings on another PC that has installed the AS 2.3. I installed the CMake the LLDB from the command line: "sdkmanager.bat cmake;3.6.4111459"
[image]

Why my Android Studio doesn't show the candidate not 
installed packages?
Shold I merge the downloaded command line tool folder into the android_sdk/tools?